# Unknown class <classname> error when using Screenmanager in .kv but screenmanager works fine in .py

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make this app which has multiple screens. I was creating the screenmanager in my .py file and everything was working as expected but i figured that i need to write the screenmanager in my .kv file. But it's just not working. I get this error  `kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <Home>` My home class is properly defined in my .kv file so i have no clue about why this is happening. i'm guessing that maybe i need to define the current screen somehow but idk how to. only the screenmanager and home class is worth looking at i think. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

this is my kv file

````
#:import dp kivy.metrics.dp
#:import ScreenManager kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager
#:import Screen kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager
#:set navbar_button_color (59/255, 68/255, 75/255, 1)

ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    Home:
        id: home
        name: "home_screen"
        manager: "screen_manager"
    Daily:
        id: daily
        name: "daily_screen"
        manager: "screen_manager"
    Weekly:
        id: weekly
        name: "weekly_screen"
        manager: "screen_manager"
    Monthly:
        id: monthly
        name: "monthly_screen"
        manager: "screen_manager"
    Yearly:
        id: yearly
        name: "yearly_screen"
        manager: "screen_manager"                

<MyLayout>:
    my_grid: my_grid
    expense_button: expense_button
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1,0.1
        Button:
            text: "Back"
            size_hint: 0.1,1
            # on_press:
            #     app.root.manager.current = "home_screen"
            #     app.root.manager.transition.direction = "right" 
        Button:
            text: "Home"
            size_hint: 0.1,1
        Button:
            text: "Daily"
            size_hint: 0.1,1
        Button:
            text: "Weekly"
            size_hint: 0.1,1
        Button:
            text: "Monthly" 
            size_hint: 0.1,1  
        Button:
            text: "Load" 
            size_hint: 0.1,1 
            on_press: my_grid.load()               
        Button:
            text: "Save" 
            size_hint: 0.1,1 
            on_press: my_grid.save() 
        Label:
            text: dt.today().strftime("%d %B %Y")
            size_hint: 0.3,1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: 59/255, 78/255, 85/255,1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos                  
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1,0.15
        Button:
            text: "EXPENSES"            
        Button:
            text: "REVENUE"    
    HeaderBox:
    MyScroll:    
        MyGrid:
            id: my_grid
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.minimum_height 
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"horizontal"
        size_hint: 1,0.2       
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Button:
                id: expense_button
                text: "Expense Total:"
                font_size: dp(20)
                on_press:
                    self.text = "Expense Total: " + str(my_grid.expense_total)
                    revenue_button.text = "Revenue Total: " + str(my_grid.revenue_total)
                    profit_button.text = "Profit: " + str(my_grid.profit)
            Button:
                id: revenue_button
                text: "Revenue Total: " 
                font_size: dp(20)
                on_press:
                    expense_button.text = "Expense Total: " + str(my_grid.expense_total)
                    self.text = "Revenue Total: " + str(my_grid.revenue_total)
                    profit_button.text = "Profit: " + str(my_grid.profit)
        Button:
            id: profit_button
            text: "Profit:"
            font_size: dp(40)       
            on_press:
                expense_button.text = "Expense Total: " + str(my_grid.expense_total)
                revenue_button.text = "Revenue Total: " + str(my_grid.revenue_total)
                self.text = "Profit: " + str(my_grid.profit)            

<Home>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint: 0.65, 1
            spacing: 5
            padding: 5
            Button:
                text: "Daily"
                font_size: 40
                size_hint: 1, 0.75
                background_color: 59/255, 68/255, 75/255, 1
                on_press:
                    root.manager.current = "daily_screen"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left" 
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 0.8
            Button:
                text: "Yearly"
                font_size: 40  
                size_hint: 1, 0.25
                background_color: 101/255, 115/255, 131/255, 1
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint: 0.35,1
            spacing: 5
            padding: [0,5,5,5]
            Button:
                text: "Weekly"
                font_size: 40
                size_hint: 1, 0.50
                background_color: 84/255, 98/255, 111/255, 1
            Button:
                text: "Monthly"
                font_size: 40  
                size_hint: 1, 0.50
                background_color: 152/255, 175/255, 199/255, 1

<Daily>:
    MyLayout:    
<Weekly>:
    Label:
        text:"Weekly"
<Monthly>:
    Label: 
        text:"Monthly"
<Yearly>:        ```
````

#for @ApuCoder
#i saw a similar question and changed the return statement of my App class. now it throws a different error. Also i don't think the home class is causing the issue, coz i removed that class n then it said the next class was undefined. so it's something else. Anyway, i have a new error to deal with now.

root.manager.current = "daily_screen"
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'current'```

```
class Home(Screen):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("sample1.kv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: @ApuCoder i hope you can help me  yet another time. Thank You

Comment: Did you define your class `Home` anywhere in `.py` ? If no, that's the reason you're getting this error; if yes try posting it.

Comment: Thank you for replying and yes i have defined Home class, i'm gonna post it there. can you please take a look?

Comment: @ApuCoder the new error is caused by the "Daily" Button in my Home class

Comment: okay. My problem was solved using ```on_press: app.root.current = "daily_screen"``` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your code, let's try to address those one by one.

**1**. In `kvlang` you either design a predefined class from `.py` or a class defined within itself. Thus either you'll do in `.py`

```py
class MyButton(Button):
    # Some prop. and/or methods if needed.
    # Otherwise,
    pass
```

Then in `kvlang` for this class,

```py
<MyButton>:
    # Whatever you want...
```

Or equivalently you can define and design that class ([dynamic](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#dynamic-classes) class ) in `kvlang` as,

```py
<MyButton@Button>:
    # Here is your design rule.
```

Now without inheriting a new class (not a default one) from a `Widget` (or to be precise from `EventDispatcher`) if you try to design it within `kvlang` a `FactoryException` will be raised.

**2**. The `Screen` widgets has a read-only property [`manager`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen.manager) that is essentially a `ScreenManager` widget. Thus when you do something like this,

```py
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    Home:
        id: home
        name: "home_screen"
        manager: "screen_manager"
```

i.e. assigning a string to it, you just overwrite its default manager by a string, that's why you got the error message `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'current'` when you tried something like this

```
root.manager.current = "daily_screen"
```

from that screen.

What you need to do is,

```py
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager # Pass this id to the screen.
    Home:
        id: home
        name: "home_screen"
        manager: screen_manager # Although its not necessary to pass it over.
```

Also I think you can't assign it in python as it is a read-only property. In `kvlang`, perhaps this is different.

Comment: okay. That shed a lot of light to my unseen issues. Thanks a lot @ApuCoder

Comment: i'm sorry to bother you again but are you talking about the manager property in the very last line? And from what i'm understanding you said it works even without passing anything to the manager property, is that right?  And i have one more question, is it possible to use the same screenmanager from the py as well as the kv file. for example i have few buttons defined in py file and i want them to change screens. Any help is appreciated

Comment: That depends on the root widget of the app class, consider posting a separate [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Okay. I'm gonna continue searching online for a solution or guidance and if nothing helps then i will post a new question. Thank you, you've been great help and inspiration through this project. Much needed.